# Swipe to delete button for iOS in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ajax

I was just on Facebook on my iPod in Safari and whenever you are in messenger and you swipe to the right/left on any message a delete button comes up.

Can someone guide me and possible tell me how it's done in html/JS/jQuery?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It could be a UITableView.. TableView has that property

Comment: Is there any way to do this in PLAIN html/jquery/AJAX?

Comment: Look at this JS lib https://github.com/mishk0/swiped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about jQuery mobile, which would be an easier way to do this, but here's how you can do it in plain ol' JS:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;//don't know how mobile browsers behave here
    var startCoordinates = {x:e.changedTouches[0].clientX,
                            y:e.changedTouches[0].clientY};
    var endHandler = function(e)
    {
        e = e || window.e;
        var xDiff = Math.abs(Math.abs(startCoordinates.x) - 
                             Math.abs(e.changedTouches[0].clientX));
        //unbind handler, avoid double listeners
        document.body.removeEventListener('touchend', endHandler, false);
        if (xDiff >= 50)
        {//assume small movement wasn't intended as swipe
            //here a swipe was detected
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete X?'))
            {//perform xhr request here, or whatever
            }
        }
    };
    document.body.addEventListener('touchend',endHandler,false);
},false);
```

jQmobile will probably be a lot easier, but this is the basic idea I think, that works on all mobile browsers I've written scripts for (Android, iOS (4 through 6), even chrome in dev-mode supporting touch events works with code like this).

*Update:*
Added code, that deals with swipes specifically:

```
(function(G,und)
{
    'use strict';
    var load = function()
    {
        var tStart, body = document.body;
        tStart = function(e)
        {
            e = e || G.event;
            var coords = e.changedTouches[0].clientX,
            tEnd = function(e)
            {
                e = e || G.event;
                var currentX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
                if (body.removeEventListener)
                {
                    body.removeEventListener('touchend',tEnd,false);
                }
                else
                {//shouldn't be possible, but I don't know all browsers, of course
                    body.detachEvent('ontouchend',tEnd);
                }
                if ((coords - currentX) <= 50)
                {//too little movement
                    /*console.log*/alert('moved, but no real swipe');
                }
                else
                {
                    /*console.log*/alert('SWIIIPEEE!');
                }
            };
            if (body.addEventListener)
            {
                return body.addEventListener('touchend',tEnd,false);
            }
            body.attachEvent('ontouchend',tEnd);
        };
        if (G.removeEventListener)
        {
            body.addEventListener('touchstart',tStart,false);
            return G.removeEventListener('load',load,false);
        }
        body.attachEvent('ontouchstart',tStart);
        return G.detachEvent('onload',load);
    };
    if (G.addEventListener)
    {
        return G.addEventListener('load',load,false);
    }
    return G.attachEvent('onload',load);
}(this));
```

Comment: Ugh.. I haven't used JS in a month. So instead of `document.body`, I can put `document.getElementById('test')`, and it'll work, right?

Comment: Do you mind providing a JFiddle/HTMLBin example? I can't seem to get it working...

Comment: @Vlad1k: if you use `document.getElementById`, you'll only pick up on touch events that occur either directly on that element, or its children. By using `document.body`, you'll be able to delegate the event. As for a fiddle: I'll look into it, but I'm somewhat pressed for time. [Here's an example using some of the same techniques](http://lysias.be/NEW/woorden.php), still work in progress, but [here's the script](http://lysias.be/NEW/navdiv.js) behind it, works on iOS and android, as well as IE > 6, FF, chrome, safari etc...

Comment: When I try to do it, nothing happens. :/

Comment: @Vlad1k: Wouldn't it be easier if you were to set up a fiddle, which I can then fork, that way I know what you're trying to do, and what part needs adjusting...

Comment: I just need a working example. I am having difficulty setting it up.

Comment: I gave you a working example, it's not a swipe-thing, but just look at the code I linked to: it's a subnav menu-thingy. It works by binding and unbinding delegators all over the place, I've tested that, and it works like a treat!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24575/discussion-between-vlad1k-and-elias-van-ootegem)

Answer (score 1):

I created a Javascript library to do this - just released it today! https://github.com/ankane/swipeout

Answer (score 0):

This will allow the user to swipe and click;

This is used in conjunction with **bootstrap** for styling and knockout for the binding (but this is optional and not used in this demo).

Working and tested on **iOS** and **Android** (Cordova App). *Due to my array having critical information, I decided to swipe to show a delete button and then allow the user to click this button. This would act as the user making a decision to delete this.*

Also I use this code not just for deletes just style the addon button appropriately ('btn-success' etc).

An extension to the jquery library needed is '**jquery.event.move**' (https://github.com/stephband/jquery.event.move)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 btn-group-vertical">
    <!-- ko foreach: Alert -->
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default mySwipe" role="button" style="height:45px;float:left;">This is also test</a>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-addOn" style="width:0px;display:none;right:0px;height:45px;margin-top:0px;padding:10px;">Delete Alert</button>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

JS:

This would be called everytime the array changes (swipeButton('.mySwipe');)

```
// THIS FUNCTION APPLIES THE SWIPE DELETE LOGIC TO LIST ITEMS (.btn)
function swipeButton(elementIdentifier) {
    $(elementIdentifier).on('movestart', function (e) {
        // If the movestart is heading off in an upwards or downwards 
        // direction, prevent it so that the browser scrolls normally.
        if ((e.distX > e.distY && e.distX < -e.distY) || (e.distX < e.distY && e.distX > -e.distY)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            if (e.distX < 0) {
                // Left
                $(e.currentTarget).css('border-bottom-right-radius', '0px');
                $(e.currentTarget).css('border-top-right-radius', '0px');
            }
        }
    }).on('move', function (e) {
        var item = $(e.currentTarget);
        var total = item.parent().width();
        var btn = $(e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling);

        if (e.distX < 0) {
            // Left
            var distance = e.distX * -1;
            distance = distance > 120 ? 120 : distance;
            btn.show();
            // Move
            var itemWidth = total - distance;
            var btnWidth = distance < 35 ? 0 : distance;
            if (btnWidth == 0) {
                btn.hide();
                itemWidth = total;
            }
            item.css('width', itemWidth + 'px');
            btn.css('width', btnWidth + 'px');
        }
        else {
            //Right
            var distance = e.distX;
            distance = distance > 120 ? 120 : distance;
            var currentWidth = item.width();
            // Move
            var thisMove = e.deltaX == 0 ? distance : e.deltaX;
            var itemWidth = currentWidth + thisMove;
            itemWidth = itemWidth > total ? total : itemWidth;
            var btnWidth = total - itemWidth;
            btnWidth = btnWidth < 14 ? 0 : btnWidth;
            if (btnWidth == 0) {
                btn.hide();
                itemWidth = total;
            }
            item.css('width', itemWidth + 'px');
            btn.css('width', btnWidth + 'px');
        }
    }).on('moveend', function (e) {
        var total = $(e.currentTarget).parent().width();
        var itemWidth = $(e.currentTarget).width();
        if (itemWidth == total) {
            // End Right
            $(e.currentTarget).css('border-bottom-right-radius', '');
            $(e.currentTarget).css('border-top-right-radius', '');
            var btn = $(e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling);
            btn.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Working demo of this code: http://jsfiddle.net/3d9n9cdo/5/